# typeerror: unbound method start_preview() must be called with PiCamera instance as first argument(got nothing instead)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Anyone facing this issue when using raspberry-pi? The code below:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
pir = MotionSensor(4)
while True:
    pir.wait_for_motion()
    camera.start_preview()
    pir.wait_for_no_motion()
    camera.stop_preview()
```

Full trace:

```
traceback(most recent call last);
file "/home/pi/motion.py", line 11, in<module>
camera.start_preview()
typeError : unbound method start_preview() must be called with PiCamera instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

---

@owenbradstreet

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/motion.py",line 7,in<module>
   with picamera.PiCamera()as camera:
  File "/usr/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera`enter code here`.py",line 415, in_init_
   self.init_camera(camera_num,sereo_mode,stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages/picamera.py".line 444. in _init_camera
   "Camera is not enabled.Try running 'sudo raspi-config'"
PiCameraError:Camera is not enabled.
```

Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
the thing is i have already enable camera :(

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi camera can be VERY finicky. Make sure the camera instantiation isn't throwing an error and that the sunny connector is really in there. But more likely the issue, the camera needs a couple seconds to start up on first preview. Try adding a `time.sleep(2)` after the first `start_preview()` (you might want to add one before your while loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import picamera

pir = MotionSensor(4)

while True:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (*YOUR LENGTH HERE*, *YOUR WIDTH HERE*)
        pir.wait_for_motion()
        camera.start_preview()
        pir.wait_for_no_motion()
        camera.stop_preview()
```

All this does is `import picamera` separately, and execute the code after with the camera as 'camera'. This also means you don't need to close the stream.

Hope this helps!